# UITableView cells with Text Fields and other controls

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xamarin.ios, xamarin

In Xamarin, I want to be able to create a UITableView with the cells to have Text Fields and other controls possibly.  How can this be done through the Xcode Interface Builder (or though the Xamarin iOS Designer)?

I would like it to look something like this:

[image]

Can someone walk me through doing this?

Bill

Comment: Please find Then Ask any question don't waste your Time and my also

Comment: Sorry to waist your time. This one has really stumped me and I have been searching all around but can't figure it out.  I really would appreciate you not comment unless it is constructive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved through Xcode Interface Builder as follows:

1. Add `UITableView` to your view
2. Type `UITableViewCell` in the Object Library and drag & drop a "Table View Cell" item to the "Table View" in the View Controller Scene, so that "Table View Cell" is added as a subview for the `UITableView`. As result, the "Table View Cell" item appears in the storyboard in the table view under the "Prototype Cells" section.
3. Add any UI elements (labels, text fields, buttons, etc) as subviews for the Table View Cell's Content View.
4. To have several different cells types, create several prototype cells (i.e. drag & drop one more `UITableViewCell` onto "Table View").
5. To distinguish different types of cell prototypes, please enter cell identifiers into Table View Cell's attributes pane.
6. Set up outlets (`UITableView`'s delegate & data source, outlets for cells' content view's subviews, etc) and actions.

I've attached an Interface Builder's screenshot demonstrating 2 types of cells added to a table view (one with a label and a text field, another with a label and a button).

[image: screenshot]

[direct link to a larger image](http://oi61.tinypic.com/11vsc94.jpg)